# JavaFX Changing Text Displaying Score to Animation and Setting Back to Score

Tags: animation, javafx, text

I am currently making a 2-player game of pong that displays the score of each side. I am looking to display the score throughout the entire game, but when someone scores, I would like a "GOAL!" (letter by letter to a short pause at the end) animation to be set as the text rather than the team's points (just how it shows in some sports shown on tv), and then be set back to the new score after. I am having troubles with this section, here is what I have:

This is my code for displaying the animation(not sure if this is right, haven't been able to test it because it won't display!):

```
public void displayGoal(int homeOrAway)
{
    String str = "GOAL!";
    if(homeOrAway == 0)
    {
        final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                event -> {
                    if (i.get() > str.length()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                        textHomeScore.setText("" + getHomeScore() + "");
                    } else {
                        textHomeScore.setText(str.substring(0, i.get()));
                        i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.play();
    }
    else
    {
        final IntegerProperty i = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        KeyFrame keyFrame = new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(1),
                event -> {
                    if (i.get() > str.length()) {
                        timeline.stop();
                        textAwayScore.setText(""+ getAwayScore() + "");
                    } else {
                        textAwayScore.setText(str.substring(0, i.get()));
                        i.set(i.get() + 1);
                    }
                });
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(keyFrame);
        timeline.play();
    }
}
```

textAwayScore and textHomeScore are just normal Texts, not TextFields.

Without this function, the scores display perfectly fine and they count up everytime the ball goes past the paddle. It would be nice to add this animation to whichever side gets the point, so any help to accomplish this is greatly appreciated. If anyone needs any clarification please let me know and I will clarify something! Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: By default a timeline runs only once. Every time the method is executed you create a new `IntegerProperty` initialized with 0. For this reason `i.get()` always returns `0` in the event handler of the `KeyFrame`. Use `timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);`.